# Collect output of script and publish it to confluence in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, confluence

I have a shell script that logs on to the given server, finds all the wars running on the same and prints their name and versions to the console. 
I need to take this output and display it on a page in confluence.

I went through this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin) for Jenkins and can connect and print static stuff on the page I provide.

The output that my script creates is dynamic, how do I, say store it in a variable and use it in the: Post-build Actions -> Publish to confluence -> Wiki Markup Replacements.

I have googled around and played with Jenkins to get these results, to no avail. I have seen '/env-vars.html' page, but none of these are of use to me, for my data is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I referred [this](https://sathishpk.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/how-to-passget-parameters-from-shell-command-into-jenkins-other-places/) to accomplish this task.